# Time conversion program

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding my program. We have to do a time conversion using a time class. Hours are to be stored in military time (0-23).It's supposed to display the time object in HH:MM format based on a 12 hour clock. Use AM and PM to display based on 12 hour clock. For example 13:30 would be 1:00. Mine is having issues distinguishing between AM and PM, it does the calculations correctly. Also We have to do an example where we enter 10:30 and add 122 minutes and the final time should be 12:32, but it keeps displaying 12:92? Thank you so much in advance, I'd greatly appreciate some help, I've been working on this for hours.

P.S How do you get it to show for example 12:00, for me it always displays 12:0

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Time
{
private:
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    char selection;
public:
    Time();
    void militaryClock();
    int getHours();
    void setHours();
    int getMinutes();
    void setMinutes();
    void minutesAdded();
};
Time::Time()
{
    minutes = 00; //Defaults to 0, if user doesn't want to enter minutes
}
int Time::getHours()
{
    return hours;
}
int Time::getMinutes()
{
    return minutes;
}
void Time::setHours()
{
    this -> hours = hours;
}
void Time::setMinutes()
{
    this -> minutes = minutes;
}
void Time::militaryClock()
{
    cout << "Please enter the hour in military hours (1-24):\n ";
    cin >> hours;

    if(hours >= 25)
    {
        cout << "Sorry that's not a valid number, please try again!\n ";
    }

    cout << "Would you like to enter the minutes? Press <Y> for yes, or <N> for no:\n ";
    cin >> selection;

    if(selection == 'y' || selection == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "Please enter the minutes:\n ";
        cin >> minutes;
    }
    else if(selection == 'n' || selection == 'N')
    {
        cout << "Since you chose not to input minutes, it will default to 0!\n ";
        Time(); //Calls the constructor to store as 00
    }
    if(hours >= 13 && hours <= 23)
    {
        cout<< "The military time you entered was:\n " << hours << ":" << minutes << endl;

        cout << "The standard time in HH:MM is:\n ";

        cout << (hours-12) << ":" << minutes << " P.M" << endl;
    }
    else if (hours == 12)
    {
        cout<<"\nThe time you entered is " << hours << ":" << minutes << " P.M" << endl;
    }
    else if(hours > 0 || hours <= 11)
    {
        cout << "\nThe time you entered is standard time " << hours << ":" << minutes << " A.M" << endl;
    }
}
void Time::minutesAdded()
{
    int nTime, addedMinutes;
    int hour12 = hours-12;

    cout << "Please enter the amount of minute(s) you would like to add?\n ";
    cin >> addedMinutes;

    nTime = minutes + addedMinutes;

    if(nTime >= 60)
    {
        cout << "The original time(hours) with the new additional minutes is --> "
        << (hour12+1)  << ":" << (nTime - 60) << " P.M" << endl;

        cout << "The final time is --> " << (hour12 + 1) << ":" << (nTime - 60) << " P.M" << endl;
    }
    else if(nTime <= 60)
    {
        cout << "The initial time with added minutes is " << hours << ":" << nTime << " A.M" << endl;

       // cout << "\nThe final time is --> " << hour12 << ":" << nTime << " A.M" << endl << endl;
    }

}
int main()
{
    Time clock;

    clock.militaryClock();
    clock.getHours();
    clock.setHours();
    clock.getMinutes();
    clock.setMinutes();
    clock.minutesAdded();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "issues distinguishing between AM and PM". Is it that you enter a time in the afternoon, e.g. 12pm, then add minutes and it becomes am? That's because minutesAdded() is using the number of minutes to determine whether it's the morning or evening. You would be better off calculating the time -- meaning the whole time, hours and minutes, not just minutes -- before printing out the time. You have made a start with

```
nTime = minutes + addedMinutes;
```

but don't stop there. As long as the accumulated minutes value is >= 60, you have to take off 60 minutes and bump the hours up by one. Not just once. If you add 122 minutes, you have to take TWO lots of 60 minutes off. Does that sound like a while loop? No, not unless you want the teacher to laugh at your code! Look up the operators for division and remainder. You're trying to do the calculation and the output in one step. That's difficult. Work out the value first, then print it afterwards.

Oh, and by the way, don't forget about what happens if you add 200 minutes to 23:00...

When you are working out the time after adding the minutes, why do you not use the hours and minutes variables? If you add some minutes to your time, the time should be changed, meaning the minutes and/or hours members should be updated.

You should have a method to add the minutes -- not to read the amount to be added, and then print out the time with the minutes added, just a method to add the minutes.

```
void Time::incrementMinutes(int nMinutes)
{
    ...the code to update hours and minutes variables correctly 
       is left as an exercise...
}
```

Then after you have got addedMinutes from cin, call

```
incrementMinutes(addedMinutes);
```

Then you could make a method to print the time, printTime() which sends the time to cout. That would then be used by minutesAdded() and by militaryClock(), so you don't have to worry in BOTH places about all the conditions for whether it's AM or PM. You only have to get that right in printTime().

Now, about the structure of your program.

First, the constructor should construct the object, set everything in it. It gets called automatically when an instance is constructed, to set up the whole instance. It's not the way to just set one field. Please write a different method to set the minutes to 0 if you are not constructing a Time object.

Maybe setMinutes was to have been that method. But setMinutes() is

```
void Time::setMinutes()
{
    this -> minutes = minutes;
}
```

That doesn't do anything. Within the method of an object, the member name refers to the member of the object (unless overridden by the same name in a closer scope). So within this function, 'minutes' means the same as 'this->minutes'.

Maybe you intended something like this instead?

```
void Time::setMinutes(int newMinutes)
{
    minutes = newMinutes;
}
```

That would at least set this->minutes to a certain value. Then, to set minutes to 0, you don't call Time(), you call setMinutes(0).

Finally, you can tell cout to use 2 characters for minutes, by piping setw(2) before the number; you can tell it to use the value '0' for the extra character by piping in setfill('0'). You have to #include  to get this stuff. So

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << 1 << ":" << setw(2) << 2 << endl;
}
```

will output 
01:02
The setfill('0') means any padding will be done with '0'; the setw(2) means the single next thing output will be padded to 2 chars.

Hope that helps... without doing your homework for you...